# Using JS/JQuery to serve ads from a self-hosted advertisements solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm working on a custom (self-hosted) ads solution that allows the users to create ad units (by uploading the banner image and target URL) and get the ad display code. A JSON response is returned (by the endpoint) for the requested ad. As of now, here is what I do to get and display the ad on the page where ad code is added:

JSON output at the endpoint:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "ad_url": "https:\/\/adlandingpage.com",
    "ad_banner": "http:\/\/localhost\/ads\/complete\/uploads\/banners\/add-banner.gif"
}
```

Content of rw-ads.js:

```
var getAds = function(ad_id, callback) {
  url = 'http://localhost/ads/complete/index.php/ads/adjson/'+ad_id+'/';
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('get', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if(status == 200) {
      callback(null, xhr.response);
    } else {
      callback(status);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};
```

Ad code to be added to a page:

```
<div id="ad1"></div>
<script src="http://myadsplatform.tld/assets/js/rw-ads.js"></script>
<script>
    var ad_id = 1;
    getAds(ad_id, function(err, data) {
        if(data.success) {
           $('#ad1').html('<a href="'+data.ad_url+'"><img style="max-width: 100%;" src="'+data.ad_banner+'"></a>'); 
        }
    });
</script>
```

I need suggestions from experts. Am I doing this correctly or this can be improved? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**A few suggestions:**

1. A function declaration is a bit simpler and more robust regarding hoisting compared to a function expression which assigns an anonymous function to a variable.
2. Supplying `null` as the first callback parameter on success is a bit quirky, either always supply the HTTP status or fail silently without calling the callback. If needed you can always introduce an error callback which might be called on `xhr.onerror`, too.
3. The `async` parameter of xhr.open defaults to `true` and can be removed
4. Your `getAds` function could be split into a generic `getJSON` function and a `getAd` function which supplies the specific ad URL to the former.
5. Your current `getAds` callback requires knowledge about the specific JSON returned by your ad server. This logic should be part of your "rw-ads.js" library and e.g. become part of the new `getAd` function.

**Exemplary code:**

```
function getJSON(url, success) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('get', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      success(xhr.response);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};

function getAd(id, success) {
  getJSON('http://localhost/ads/complete/index.php/ads/adjson/' + id, function(data) {
    if (data.success) {
      success('<a href="' + data.ad_url + '"><img style="max-width: 100%;" src="' + data.ad_banner + '"></a>');
    }
  });
}

getAd(1, function(html) {
  document.getElementById('ad1').innerHTML = html;
}
```

**General considerations:**

Since you don't rely on an external ad network but a self-hosted solution, you might want to inject your ads into your HTML document on the server side, without the asynchronous client side ajax request.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Regarding your last paragraph, I want the users of this script to embed ad code on other sites as well. I'm going to try the functions you wrote. Thanks again.